# How to get a field value in a DetailView

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to get access to a field in a detailview and display it in a label.  Note, i have converted the field into a templdate field.  I am not getting anything in the Output label.  what am i doing wrong here? thanks

```
if (this.DetailsView1.DefaultMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit) 
        { 

            { 
                TextBox dv = this.DetailsView1.FindControl("ID") as TextBox; 
                // dv.Text = "RCA Assigned"; 
                Session["MySessionVar"] = dv; 
                OutputLabel.Text = (string)Session["MySessionVar"]; 
            } 
        } 

        else 
        { 
            TextBox dv = this.DetailsView1.FindControl("ID") as TextBox; 
            OutputLabel.Text = (string)Session["MySessionVar"]; 
        }
```

Comment: What is your field? ID(textbox) or mySessionvar?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

You're storing the entire TextBox (dv) in the Session. Then you're trying to cast it to a string.

Instead you should do:

```
Session["MySessionVar"] = dv.Text;
```

Meaning a string gets stored in Session from the outset (boxed as an object, hence the need to cast back to a string when you get it out again).
However, why are you using Session at all? If you simply want the content of the TextBox to appear in the OutputLabel then this should do the trick:

```
TextBox dv = this.DetailsView1.FindControl("ID") as TextBox;     
OutputLabel.Text = dv.Text;
```

But the content of the label will only be filled each time the page is served by the Web Server. If you want the content of the Label to change dynamically as you edit the content of the TextBox, you'll need to look at a JavaScript, client-side solution of some kind.

It really depends what you're trying to achieve here. Could you provide some more background detail in the question?

Comment: thanks, i have changed and still the output label is showing no ID.

Comment: okay i have done what you suggested and i am not using any session but getting this error now: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  thanks

Comment: all what i am trying to do to access the ID in the detailview and show it on the label i created.  that is it.  thanks